# Как в одном input совместить два name

Tags: html

Как в одном `input` совместить два `name`? Есть два обработчика  `file` и `files[]`,  их нужно совместить в одном `name=''`.  Можно ли это реализовать? Обработчик `file` загружает файлы в нужную папку с помощью `PHP`. Обработчик `file[]` выводит ошибки и делает обработку файлов `bootstrap`, с помощью `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте атрибуты `data` вот [подробная статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/139210/) 
или спрячь элемент

```
<input type="hidden" id="postId" name="postId" value="34657">
```